# Storing a pointer to an instance of a class (this doesnt work)

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am in the process of creating a very simple component based game engine. I have an entity class that stores a list of components to iterate through.

The entity class also stores info like name, position, scale whatever.What I need is for each component to store a reference to the entity instance that owns it. I originally tried using the "this" keyword but it doesnt work as you cannot use it in assignments.

```
void Entity::addComponent(Component *theComponent){
    components.push_back(theComponent);
    theComponent->ownerEntity = this;
}
```

How can the component store a pointer to its owner?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: The component class has pretty much nothing in it as its intended to be inherited but here is its declaration:

```
class Entity;

class Component
{
    public:
        Component();
        virtual void Update();
        Entity *ownerEntity;
    protected:
    private:

};
```

When Making a component if I try and access the owner entity like so:

```
rotation = ownerEntity->GetRotation;
```

I get this error:

```
error: argument of type 'float (Entity::)()' does not match 'float'
```

Comment: show the Component class please

Comment: If you model ownership, do *not* use a raw pointer. Use a smart pointer.

Comment: "I originally tried using the "this" keyword but it doesnt work as you cannot use it in assignments." I don't know where you got this idea. There's nothing wrong about using `this` as the right hand side of assignment. You need to better describe the problem you're facing, because the current description is that of a non-problem.

Comment: You need to be more specific than "it doesn't work" what happens, will it compile? If not what compiler are you using and what does it say? If it compiles does it not run as you expect? Does it crash?

Comment: @DavidC The code you’ve shown us *will work* (it’s still not very good code, see above about pointers and ownership, and it also has too many public members …). So: What do you mean by “doesn’t work”?

Comment: Oh my god I feel like an idiot

Comment: I think this question should be removed/closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rotation = ownerEntity->GetRotation;
```

should be:

```
rotation = ownerEntity->GetRotation();
```

to call the function.

Comment: We all make mistakes. Next time you'll spot this one really quickly I bet!